# Wayland + Terminator + Quake mode

Tags: ubuntu, wayland, terminator

I do not mind to switch to Wayland but only one thing is stopping me. I am attached so much to Terminator and I still have no idea how to enable F12 for show/hide of Terminator on Wayland. I wonder even if this is possible? The exact question is how can I enable Terminator to have quake mode (using F12) to make it show/hide in Wayland?

Comment: If anyone has a similar problem: I switched to tilix + quake-mode. It works even better than terminator.